# Null Reference exception in Admob Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to implement the AdMob in my unity project but the console shows Null reference exception. I have already added the adsmanager to the main camera. The error shows it is in the inbuilt admob script that I have imported with the unity plugin Need help!

I tried creating a separate empty object in the scene and assigning the admanager script to it but it still didn't work.

//This is my admanager script

```
public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour {


    public static AdsManager Instance { set; get; }

    private string bannerId = "ca-app-pub-5467477354717653/3662828208";
    private string videoId = "ca-app-pub-5467477354717653/7188684836";

    void Start () {

          Instance = this;
         DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        if(Instance = null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Instance is Null");
            Instance = this;
        }

        Admob.Instance().initSDK("ca-app-pub-5467477354717653~6427758194 ", new AdProperties());
        AdProperties adProperties = new AdProperties();
        adProperties.isTesting = true;

        //#if UNITY_EDITOR

        //#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        Admob.Instance().initAdmob(bannerId,videoId);
        Admob.Instance().loadInterstitial(videoId);

        //#endif

    }
```

//Admob inbuilt script Error Lines

jadmob.Call("setListener", new object[] {new AdmobListenerProxy(innerlistener) });

jadmob.Call ("initSDK", new object[]{appid,value.toString()});

Comment: //Admob Inbuilt Script

Comment: private AndroidJavaObject jadmob;
   private void preInitAdmob(){
            if (jadmob == null) {
                AndroidJavaClass admobUnityPluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.admob.plugin.AdmobUnityPlugin");
                jadmob = admobUnityPluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance");
                InnerAdmobListener innerlistener = new InnerAdmobListener();
                innerlistener.admobInstance = this;
                jadmob.Call("setListener", new object[] {new AdmobListenerProxy(innerlistener) });                                          
   }
  }

Comment: public void initSDK(string appid,AdProperties value)
  {
            if(value==null){
                value = new AdProperties();
   }
   jadmob.Call ("initSDK", new object[]{appid,value.toString()});                                                                  
  }

Comment: You should edit your question, not provide extra information as comments.